# OpenCV3/iOS: Custom built - howto change configuration parameters

Tags: ios, opencv, cmake, configure, opencv3.0

How can I change the configuration when compiling an iOS framework using the `build_framework.py` script which ships with the OpenCV package?
In detail, I want to disable "libpng" support and altered the cmakeargs part as follows:

```
cmakeargs = ("-GXcode " +
            "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_PNG=OFF" +
            "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=%s/platforms/ios/cmake/Toolchains/Toolchain-%s_Xcode.cmake " +
            "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=\"-Wno-implicit-function-declaration\" " +
            "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=install") % (srcroot, target)
```

But the option `-DBUILD_PNG=OFF`is ignored and libpng is included. How can I change the configuration in the script?

Comment: Because your question is very specific (OpenCV, using build_framework.py, disabling png). `-DWITH_PNG=NO` is not the way CMake handles it. So I doubt this question/answer will be helpful for others. Your opinion might differ though.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the PNG configure check with `-DCMAKE_DISABLE_FIND_PACKAGE_PNG=TRUE`

This is [possible with CMake 2.8.6](https://blogs.kde.org/2011/11/11/cool-new-stuff-cmake-286-3-standard-way-disable-optional-packages) and newer.

Comment: Thanks but this will just disable searching for the library. The correct means to disable png support is ``-DWITH_PNG=NO``

Answer (score 0):

The actual correct parameter is:

```
-DWITH_PNG=NO
```